# Direction of electron flow in X-ray Tube in X-ray Crystallography

Tags: electrochemistry, x-ray-diffraction

In X-ray crystallography, X-ray tube may be used to generate X-ray. The set-up is the following:

[image: X-ray tube]

Here it shows the electron beam goes from cathode to anode. If anode is the negative electrode, why will electron travel towards it? Why don't electrons travel from anode to cathode?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the anode is the negative electrode?

Comment: A negative particle goes to the anode.

Comment: @AChem isn't by definition the anode is the negative electrode?

Comment: @YushiLi, No. You might be confusing the electrochemical terminology. For a DC source, in evacuated glass tubes, anode is the electrode which is connected to the positive terminal of the DC source. So, here in the X-ray tube, anode is the positive electrode.

Comment: In context of electrochemistry, anodes are electrodes where oxidation occurs, positive in the passive, electrolytic mode, negative in active, galvanic mode. In context of physics, circuits and vacuum bulbs, anodes are positive electrodes.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

For one, the question potentially displays confusion about *electric current* as either *flow of positive charge* (and *by convention*, the direction of electric current among e.g., electricians from $+ \rightarrow{} -$), or *flow of electrons*.  See e.g., Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current#Conventions) about this:

[image]

For two, the anode of X-ray tubes not only is where the electrons travel to, but often literally is called the *target* they hit, because its composition has a great influence on the [brightness](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Brightness), [brilliance](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Brilliance), the position of the [characteristic emissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_X-ray) (in first approximation e.g., $\ce{Mo} K\alpha \approx \pu{0.71 Å}$, $\ce{Cu} K \alpha \approx \pu{1.54 Å}$), and underlying bremsstrahlung of such a source.  As they carry much energy to a small spot, largely released as heat, you need good cooling (water on the backside of the anode, the Coolidge X-ray tube), use a *rotating disc* as target (a frequently used design in protein crystallography), or switch to a liquid jet altogether (one form of a  microfocus source).

[image]

(image credit English Wikipedia, [X-ray tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_tube)).

---

In case the next question is where the X-ray photons travel to: the spatial distribution of their paths is not uniform (an [earlier question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151859/how-to-find-the-angle-of-emission-of-an-x-ray-during-impact-of-accelerated-catho/152113#152113)).

Comment: Thanks for the details. What I don't understand is why electrons flow towards the anode. Like your image from Wikipedia shows, the electron is flowing from negative electrode (anode) towards the positive electrode (cathode). Why here in the X-ray tube, it can be the opposite? Don't like charge repel? Thank you.

Comment: With the battery/alimenting direct current in their back, a cathode is the negative electrode and gives the electrons away (like a catapult). All while an anode accepts incoming electrons and is positive (relative to the cathode).